# How to iterate through characters and lines in Python?

Tags: python, string, loops

Let's say I have a file containing this:

```
xxoxoxoxox

xxxxxxxxxx

xoxoxoxoxo

ooxoxoxoxo
```

and I want to iterate through each character and line and store them.

I know that if the characters are separated by spaces, I can do this:

```
mylist=[]    
with open("myfile.txt") as myfile:    
    for line in file:    
        line = line.strip().split(" ")    
        first = line[0]    
        second = line[1]    
        alist = [first, second]    
        mylist.append(alist)
```

But how do I do something like this without spaces as delimiters? I tried `.split()`
and

```
for line in file:    
   for char in line:
```

But neither seems to work.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please indent your code and post the code properly.

Comment: damn, it works with leaving the .split() completely. sorry.

Comment: sorry, you can delete the question, if you think it shouldn't be on the site. I was trying to figure this out for half an hour, but now I know. I am still a newbie, but I will get better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small snippet that might be useful to you.

Say you have a file called 'doc.txt' with two lines:

```
kisskiss
bangbang
```

With the following python script:

```
  with open('doc.txt', 'r') as f:
        all_lines = []
        # loop through all lines using f.readlines() method
        for line in f.readlines():
            new_line = []
            # this is how you would loop through each alphabet
            for chars in line:
                new_line.append(chars)
            all_lines.append(new_line)
```

The output is:

```
>>> all_lines
Out[94]: 
[['k', 'i', 's', 's', 'k', 'i', 's', 's', '\n'],
 ['b', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'g', '\n']]
```

Answer (score 0):

More "pythonic" way:

```
def t():
    r = []
    with open("./test_in.txt") as f_in:
        [r.extend(list(l)) for l in f_in]
    return r
```

Note that you can't use `return [r.extend(list(l)) for l in f_in]` because extend returns None.

Comment: I wouldn't call the usage of a side-effect _pythonic_.

Comment: I don't understand, what you consider as side-effect :(

Comment: The main task of a list comprehension is the creation of a list. You use a list comprehension to call a function multiple times and throw away the created list just to have a one-liner. A `for l in f_in: r.extend(list(l))` in two lines would be the way to go.